# How to backup a file before changing it with "REX Configuration management" (rexify)

Tags: perl, configuration-management, rex

How do I backup files when making a change with [rex cm](https://www.rexify.org/docs/guides/start_using__r__ex.html) (rexify.org) - or do I have to do this manually?

I see no option in the [File.pm API](https://www.rexify.org/docs/api/1.4/rex/commands/file.pm.html) - description. I hope there is some undocumented feature.

Background: It's mostly about the initial configuration. If I push a file, I want to make sure, that potential individual changes are saved somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [release notes for rex version 0.44](http://www.rexify.org/docs/release_notes/0.44.html) mention:

> `Rex::Ext::Backup` - a simple backup module. This module creates a backup of a file before rex changes it.
>
> ```
> include qw/Rex::Ext::Backup/;
>
> set backup_location => "backup/%h";
>
> task yourtask => sub {
>    file "/etc/foo.conf", content => "new content\n";
> };
> ```

[Here](https://modules.rexify.org/module/Rex::Ext::Backup) are the docs for the module.  Google doesn't see them, probably because of the expired SSL certificate.  But there is a bit more info there:

> You can use the following modifiers for your `backup_location`.
>
> - `%h` - the hostname
> - `%t` - the time (epoch seconds)

If this doesn't work I'd reach out the the rexify folks [directly](http://www.rexify.org/support.html).

Comment: awesome, thx @chicks - thanks for the links to the documentation - is the documentation on modules.rexify.org more current then https://www.rexify.org/docs/api.html?

Comment: I don't think one is more up-to-date than the other necessarily.  The `modules.rexify.org` site seems to be the place for extensions aka modules which are not in the core documentation on `rexify.org` itself or other CPAN viewers like metacpan.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @chicks - somehow the `rexify --use=Rex::Ext::Backup` command does not work "error malformed JSON string..." but nevermind, I will contact the developers like you suggested.
Could you please be so kind to tag tag the questiong wih [rex] if appropriate

Comment: workaround: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rex-users/794tvV45OxY
quote: "[...] For those of you who find this post and need a workaround in order to load the dependencies your Rexfiles are asking for, if you clone the rex-recipes repo (https://github.com/RexOps/rex-recipes) directly, you can copy the modules your Rexfile needs into a `lib/` directory in the same directory as your Rexfile, and everything will be happy again. [...]"